# Remote Execution with Buildbarn

Tags: bazel

I am trying to setup remote build execution (RBE) with Buildbarn locally. So nothing fancy, just a remote PC I have laying around that I want to use for RBE.
I don't need remote caching and was wondering what would be the minimal setup to achieve this?
I am trying to understand what I need from the example provided [here](https://github.com/buildbarn/bb-deployments). Do I need a bb_storage instance? Does anyone have experience with this? I am a bit lost to find documentation/examples on how to achieve such a minimal setup.

Answer (score 1):

The [bb-deployments](https://github.com/buildbarn/bb-deployments) repository has some examples of hypothetical buildbarn setups - the easiest way to get started on a single machine would be a docker-compose setup, perhaps with some of the pieces in their example removed. In my estimation, you'd need:

- a single bb-scheduler instance
- at least one bb-worker / bb-runner pair to execute commands
- a single bb-storage instance, which serves as both the storage for build artifacts and the frontend for the scheduler instance (this is the piece whose address is supplied to bazel flags to enable remote execution)
- a bb-browser instance is optional, but allows one to debug/inspect build artifacts in the cache

However, understanding the buildbarn configurations can be involved for the uninitiated (requires understanding how to read the config protobuf schemas, [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/), and how JSON values map to protobuf schemas), so I'd recommend starting with their provided docker-compose, and modifying it bit by bit until it matches the configuration you're looking for.